# Unable to run Python Script from within an Ansible Playbook

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, scripting

I am trying to write an ansible playbook to crawl a website and then store its contents into a static file under aws s3 bucket. Here is the crawler code :

```py
"""
Handling pages with the Next button

"""
import sys
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url =  "https://xyz.co.uk/"
file_name = "web_content.txt"

while True:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    raw_html = soup.prettify()
    file = open(file_name, 'wb')
    print('Collecting the website contents')
    file.write(raw_html.encode())
    file.close()
    print('Saved to %s' % file_name)
    #print(type(raw_html))

    # Finding next page
    next_page_element = soup.select_one('li.next > a')
    if next_page_element:
        next_page_url = next_page_element.get('href')
        url = urljoin(url, next_page_url)
    else:
        break
```

This is my ansible-playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: create s3 bucket and upload static website content into it
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: create a s3 bucket
    amazon.aws.aws_s3:
      bucket: testbucket393647914679149
      region: ap-south-1
      mode: create

  - name: create a folder in the bucket
    amazon.aws.aws_s3:
      bucket: testbucket393647914679149
      object: /my/directory/path
      mode: create

  - name: Upgrade pip
    pip:
      name: pip
      version: 21.1.3

  - name: install virtualenv via pip
    pip:
      requirements: /root/ansible/requirements.txt
      virtualenv: /root/ansible/myvenv
      virtualenv_python: python3.6
    environment:
      PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:{{ ansible_user_dir }}/.local/bin"

  - name: Run script to crawl the website
    script: /root/ansible/beautiful_crawl.py


  - name: copy file into bucket folder
    amazon.aws.aws_s3:
      bucket: testbucket393647914679149
      object: /my/directory/path/web_content.text
      src: web_content.text
      mode: put
```

Problem is when I run this, it runs fine upto the task **name: install virtualenv via pip** and then throws following error while executing the task **name: Run script to crawl the website**:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code",                                                                                                              "rc": 2, "stderr": "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-9798                                                                                                             3643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 1: import: command not found\n/root/.ansible                                                                                                             /tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: lin                                                                                                             e 2: from: command not found\n/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-                                                                                                             13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 3: import: command not found\n/roo                                                                                                             t/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_cra                                                                                                             wl.py: line 4: from: command not found\n/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-162513770                                                                                                             0.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 6: url: command not foun                                                                                                             d\n/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beauti                                                                                                             ful_crawl.py: line 7: file_name: command not found\n/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-t                                                                                                             mp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 10: syntax e                                                                                                             rror near unexpected token `('\n/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.885430                                                                                                             6-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 10:`     response = requests.get                                                                                                             (url)'\n", "stderr_lines": ["/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-1                                                                                                             3026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 1: import: command not found", "/ro                                                                                                             ot/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_cr                                                                                                             awl.py: line 2: from: command not found", "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-162513                                                                                                             7700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 3: import: command no                                                                                                             t found", "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-9798364364546                                                                                                             6/beautiful_crawl.py: line 4: from: command not found", "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansi                                                                                                             ble-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 6: url:                                                                                                              command not found", "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97                                                                                                             983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 7: file_name: command not found", "/root/.                                                                                                             ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.                                                                                                             py: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('", "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansibl                                                                                                             e-tmp-1625137700.8854306-13026-97983643645466/beautiful_crawl.py: line 10:`                                                                                                                  response = requests.get(url)'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems.
Check the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html).

**No. 1**: The `script` modules will run `bash` scripts by default, not `python` scripts. If you want to run a python script, you need to add a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as the first line of the script or use the `executable` parameter.

**No 2**: You create a `venv`, so I assume you want to run the script in that `venv`. You can't do that out of the box with the `script` module, so you would need to work around that.

This should work for you (you don't need the shebang, as you tell the script module to run it with python in the venv using the `executable` parameter):

```yaml
  - name: Run script to crawl the website
    script: /root/ansible/beautiful_crawl.py
      executable: /root/ansible/myvenv/bin/python
```

Comment: Now, I am getting following error with installing the libraries from the requirements file itself:           "stdout: Requirements already satisifed"

Comment: Do you get this when you run the script manually on that machine (in the venv)?

Comment: I am just thinking, do I really need to run this script in the virtual environment or should I simply install necessary libraries in a single task using the ansible pip module?

Comment: `venv` is definitely cleaner, I would do it like that, but it is up to you

Comment: I get the similar message, Yes. But it doesn't mean the code should break.

Comment: Then this is not an ansible problem. You might want to consider to ask a new question about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234413/discussion-between-ankit-and-toydarian).